# Python KivyMD: How to round the corners of a MDCard widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

Is it possible to round the corners of a MDCard? I went throught the KivyMD documentation and there is a `border_radius` attribute for the MDCard class but it doesn't seem to work. I have the most recent version (according to `pip freeze`) of both Kivy (1.11.1) and KivyMD (0.104.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add...

```
MDCard:
    ....
    radius:[20,] 
    border_radius:20
    ....
```

It Works for me...

Answer (score 0):

people advise to use canvas its OK, but it increase your coding and make it very complex.
Just go to the Kivymd>uix>card.py line 631 change the default from 3dp to for example 20dp or whatever you want.
then go back to your code and type radius: [] and insert your desire number from 20 to 0. done !!!!
i spent lots of time to review the code :D :D :D Enjoy.